# Options for subsetting data in plots in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am creating a interactive plot in Shiny where the user will upload a dataset with x and y coordinates (so one column for x, and one column for y) and then Shiny will plot a scatterplot. The dataset the user uploads will have additional columns that will provide information for subsetting on. For example, this could be a dataset the user uploads (called `dat`):

```
n = 100
x = runif(n,0,100)
y = runif(n,0,100)

var1 = sample(1:100,n,replace=TRUE)
var2 = as.factor(sample(1:3,n,replace=TRUE))
var3 = sample(c("A","B"),n,replace=TRUE)

dat = data.frame(x,y,var1,var2,var3)
```

Now, I would like to have functionality such that if the user wants to only plot, say, x-y pairs such that `var1 >= 54` and `var3 == "B"` or `var2 == "3"`, or some other combination of subsetting rules, that they can specify the variable that they want to subset on, and then the criteria for subsetting.

What I was able to come up with was to allow the user to write a string of the subsetting criteria, for example just have them manually type `var1 >=54 & var3=="B"`, however, this tool is going to be used by people without programming backgrounds and so a solution that uses less programming knowledge the better.

I could also envision something that has one field, you populate it with the subsetting variable, another box for say `>, >=, =, <=, <, !=`, and then the value, and then after you fill that out another field appears if you want to further subset but I wasn't able to figure out if this is a realistic task in Shiny. Another difficulty though with this approach is how to allow the user to specify AND and OR statements.

Any help/comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue becomes a lot more complex when you need `OR` statements. If you only need `AND`, I think this can be easily solved with the built-in filtering function of `DT`.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this problem was that the number of filtering conditions should be maximized because of space issues. You can set the maximum number of filters in the `names` variable. (in the example it is set to 4)

Basically every filter is the same: they consist of a variable, a relational operator, a value and optionally a logical operator to set more filters. For these filters I used a module called `filterModuleUI`, to generate the filters with an `lapply`. The last filter doesn't need a logical operator. It is set with the `last` argument in the module function.

In the server side there is an `observeEvent` set for every filter to observe the logical operators. If these are set to `"-"` then further filters are hidden and are also set to `"-"`. i.e.: If you have 4 active filters and you set the first filter's logical operator to `"-"`, then it will hide the second, third and fourth filter.

When clicking the `apply button`, the conditions are pasted into a list of strings separated by logical operators. i.e: if there are 3 conditions:

[image]

... the string used for filtering is:`"x>6&x<20&var1>2"`.

This is evaluated using the `eval` and `parse` functions.

**Notes**:

- There is no exception handling implemented.
- This code could be further improved. Feel free to suggest an edit.

**Code below**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Set the maximum number of filters e.g: names <- paste0("in", 1:5) for a maximum of 5 filters. 
names <- paste0("in", 1:4)
inputs <- c("var", "oper", "val", "log")

# Create a UI module to reuse
filterModuleUI <- function(id, last = F){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    div(class = id,
      fluidRow(
        column(2,
          selectInput(ns("var"),
            "",
            choices = colnames(dat)
          )
        ),
        column(2,
          selectInput(ns("oper"),
            "",
            choices = c(">", ">=", "==", "<=", "<", "!=")
          )
        ),
        column(2,
          textInput(ns("val"),
            ""
          )
        ),
        if(last == F){
          column(2,
            selectInput(ns("log"),
              "",
              choices = c(
                "-" = "-",
                "AND" = "&",
                "OR" = "|"
                ),
              selected = "-"
            )
          )
        }
      )
    )
  )
}

# Load demo data
n = 100
x = runif(n,0,100)
y = runif(n,0,100)

var1 = sample(1:100,n,replace=TRUE)
var2 = as.factor(sample(1:3,n,replace=TRUE))
var3 = sample(c("A","B"),n,replace=TRUE)

dat = data.frame(x,y,var1,var2,var3)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  h3("Filter demo"),
  lapply(names, function(x){
    if(x == names[length(names)]) filterModuleUI(x, last=T)
    else filterModuleUI(x)
  }),

  actionButton("apply", "Apply filter"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  # Set observeEvent to hide further filterModule-s if the logical operator is set to "-"
  lapply(names, function(x){
    no_item <- which(names == x)
    input_log <- paste(x, "log", sep = "-")
    if(no_item != length(names)){
      observeEvent(input[[input_log]],{
        next_items <- names[(no_item + 1) : length(names)]
        if(input[[input_log]] == "-"){
          lapply(next_items, function(x){
            updateSelectInput(session, paste(x, "log", sep = "-"), selected = "-")
          })
          lapply(paste(next_items[1], inputs, sep = "-"), hide)
        }
        else lapply(paste(next_items[1], inputs, sep = "-"), show)
      })
    }
  })

  # Initialize data$a with a predefined data.frame (dat)
  data <- reactiveValues(a = dat)

  # Filter based on the selectInput-s
  observeEvent(input$apply,{
    obj <- lapply(names, function(x){
      lapply(inputs, function(y){
        paste(x, y, sep="-")
      })
    })
    # Construct filtering conditions by pasting variable, operator and value together (e.g.: x > 20)  
    condition <- lapply(obj, function(x){
      paste0(input[[x[[1]]]], input[[x[[2]]]], input[[x[[3]]]])
    })
    # Compute how many AND/OR logical operators are used
    used_cond <- sum(sapply(paste(names[-length(names)], "log", sep="-"), function(x){
      input[[x]] != "-"
    }))
    # Paste the conditions together with logical operators
    filter <- vector()
    for(i in 1:(used_cond + 1)){
      nm <- ifelse(i==1, "", input[[paste(names[i-1], "log", sep="-")]])
      filter <- paste(filter, condition[[i]], sep = nm)
    }
    # Check filter in console
    print(filter)
    # Filtering
    data$a <- dat[eval(parse(text=filter)), ]
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- data$a
    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```